# Prove that $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

In my complex analysis homework I have to show that, if $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded continuous function, then

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz = 0.$$

where $\gamma_{r}: [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ , such that $\gamma_{r}(t) = re^{it}$

How can I prove that? I tried using Cauchy's integral formula: if $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ then
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{g(z)}{z} dz = 2\pi i \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \text{Ind}_{\gamma_{r}}(0) g(0).$$
Because $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \text{Ind}_{\gamma_{r}}(0) = 1$, we have 
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{g(z)}{z} dz = 2\pi i \ g(0),$$
but how can we now evaluate $g(0)$, or am I making some mistake?

Comment: What is $\gamma_r$?

Comment: Just edited because I forgot to define $\gamma_{r}$

Comment: If you manage to prove that for a merely continuous function $f$, tell us how, please.

Comment: Take for example $f(z)=z$ and the result is $2\pi i$.

Comment: I think that the claim holds for a bounded continuous function.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that the function is bounded thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, $f(z)=z$ is a counterexample.

Indeed, 
$$\oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{z}{z^2} dz =\oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{1}{z} dz=2\pi i$$

**Addedd** If $f$ is bounded then let $|f(z)| \leq M$ for some constant $M$. Then 
$$\left| \oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz \right| \leq \oint_{\gamma_{r}}\left| \frac{f(z)}{z^2} \right| dt \leq  \frac{M}{r^2} \mbox{length}(\gamma_{r})$$

Calculate the integral on the RHS and take its limit.

Comment: If $f(z) = z^{2}$ then $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} \frac{f(z)}{z^2} dz = \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} dz$, and $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \oint_{\gamma_{r}} dz = 0$

Comment: @Eduude Ty, fixed it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that $f$ is a bounded function. $f(z) = z$ is not bounded

Comment: @Eduude See the added.

Comment: @n.s. Upon invoking the triangle inequality, the differential should be $|dz|=dt$.